# gdal multi-threading issues

Tags: c++, multithreading, gdal

I wrote a Multithread program in C++ were some threads are reading from a GdalDataset  A (with exclusive access managing) and only one thread is writing in another Gdaldataset B,

I’m getting some empty values in the resulting image

It known that Gdal is not completely thread safe but the problem is not supposed to be present here since the writing is not concurrent (only one thread is writing in the Gdaldataset object)

Note that this problem wasn’t present with GTiff driver

Any ideas to solve the problem?

Comment: The problem is very likely to be with the way you are managing concurrent access to the data. Without seeing your code, it's very difficult to say much else.

Comment: the problem was present on the data with no concurrent access (only one thread is writing on this resource)

Answer (score 0):

It is also not thread safe if reading the same GDALDataset A from within multiple threads. see answers here (https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/FAQMiscellaneous):

"One important point is that the same ​GDALDataset object should not be accessed by several threads at the same time. "